# System.out.println is not proposed in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new using IntelliJ IDEA, and I want to add `System.out.println` but this is not proposed in the IDE

[image]

Comment: Have you installed jre/jdk properly? Looks like it isn't even recognizing `String`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click Add Configuration, and choose JRE first.

Comment: Nonsense. It needs a Project SDK (JDK), not Run Configration JRE. How was this accepted?